# BluetoothAdapter in putExtra

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, adapter

I have a requirement where I want to develop a hybrid application and list the Bluetooth devices, scan and connect, share files etc.

So I want to add `BluetoothAdapter` mAdapter value into extras and pass it into onActivity result. Like `enableIntent.putExtra("", mAdapter);` and use it in `onActivityResult` by `getExtra(...)`. Is there a way to do so??..

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {  
    Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);  
    ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(enableIntent, RequestCodes.BLUETOOTH_ENABLE_CODE);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use **Application class** to store that data and use wherever you need.

Check this post for how to use [Application class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599775/how-do-i-make-global-changes-throughout-my-app-in-android/10599919#10599919).