# Send nodelist between activities

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I send a nodelist between Activities? I have an app in which there are 4 screens with four activities. In first activity I parse url to get a nodelist. When the button is clicked I need to start new activity and send nodelist to the second activity.
I tried this way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
bundle.putString("KEY","NodeList"); 

intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Please specify the meaning of `NodeList`

Comment: The NodeList interface provides the abstraction of an ordered collection of nodes, without defining or constraining how this collection is implemented. NodeList objects in the DOM are live.
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html

Answer (score 0):

Make the class that implements interface `NodeList` also implement interface [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29) method on the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is that you can use Application class so that you can set a value using Setter method in Application and can get back the values using getter method in Application class..

Data will retain until your Application exists , so you can use it..  [How to use Application class in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599775/how-do-i-make-global-changes-throughout-my-app-in-android/10599919#10599919)

Also you can use [Android Parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400564/android-parcelable-retailerorderactivity-java-return-null/7400675#7400675)